# Get a unique string from string split

Tags: list, scala

I want to get a `List[String]` from the input. Please help me to find an elegant way.

Desired output:

```
emp1,emp2
```

My code:

```
val ls = List("emp1.id1", "emp2.id2","emp2.id3","emp1.id4")

def myMethod(ls: List[String]): Unit = {
  ls.foreach(i => print(i.split('.').head))
}

(myMethod(ls)). //set operation to make it unique ??
```

Comment: What do you mean with unique here?

Comment: Please, elaborate what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def myMethod(ls: List[String]) =
  ls.map(_.takeWhile(_ != '.'))

myMethod(ls).distinct
```

Comment: This also works. Is there any difference or issue you see  ( split and head against takeWhile)
  ls.map(_.split('.').head)

Comment: I think it expresses the logic better, and it stops as soon as it hits the '.' rather than checking the whole string.

Answer (score 3):

If you care about validation, you can consider using Regex:

```
val ls = List("emp1.id1", "emp2.id2","emp2.id3","emp1.id4","boom")
  
  def myMethod(ls: List[String]) = {
    val empIdRegex = "([\\w]+)\\.([\\w]+)".r
    val employees = ls collect { case empIdRegex(emp, _) => emp }
    employees.distinct
  }

println(myMethod(ls))
```

Outputs:

```
List(emp1, emp2)
```

Comment: Perfect . Thank you So much Zvi.

Answer (score 1):

Since Scala 2.13, you can use `List.unfold` to do this:

```
List.unfold(ls) {
  case Nil =>
    None
  case x :: xs =>
    Some(x.takeWhile(_ != '.'), xs)
}.distinct
```

Please not that you want distinct values, therefore you can achieve the same using `Set.unfold`:

```
Set.unfold(ls) {
  case Nil =>
    None
  case x :: xs =>
    Some(x.takeWhile(_ != '.'), xs)
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/LrqztymuQxKybfUJDNY6sQ).